# DECLARE Error in My-sql Query

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am having query .Which i want to run on a phpmyadmin.

But whenever I run i got error at declare.
I am not able to find out what is the error in this ?

I want to run this block of code as a query from the PHP?

```
-- Declare a cursor to hold the section information for a specified product
DECLARE section_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT DISTINCT cds_especee.sectid, cds_evocee.text, min
(displayorder) displayorder
FROM cds_especee
JOIN cds_evocee ON (cds_especee.sectid = cds_evocee.id)
-- Replace the prodid below with a valid prodid from your data set
WHERE cds_especee.prodid = 'S1522339'
GROUP BY cds_especee.sectid, cds_evocee.text
ORDER BY displayorder ASC
OPEN section_cursor
-- Fetching the first section into variable
FETCH NEXT FROM section_cursor
INTO @section, @sectionname, @order
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
-- Print current section to the screen
PRINT '******'+@sectionname+'******'
-- Declare a cursor to hold the header and body information for the
specified product
-- Note that the WHERE statement limits the results to the headers and body falling under the current section
DECLARE espec_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT evoc1.text, evoc2.text, displayorder
FROM cds_especee
JOIN cds_evocee evoc1 ON (cds_especee.hdrid = evoc1.id)
JOIN cds_evocee evoc2 ON (cds_especee.bodyid = evoc2.id)
-- Replace the prodid below with a valid prodid from your data set
WHERE cds_especee.prodid = 'S1522339' AND
cds_especee.sectid = @section
ORDER BY displayorder ASC
OPEN espec_cursor
-- Fetching the first header and body into variable
FETCH NEXT FROM espec_cursor
INTO @hdr, @body, @order1
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
-- Below is a loop that prints all the headers and bodies for the
current section
BEGIN
PRINT @hdr +': '+@body
FETCH NEXT FROM espec_cursor
INTO @hdr, @body, @order1
END
-- Clear out the espec_cursor as it will be repopulated with data for
the next section as the procedure loops
CLOSE espec_cursor
DEALLOCATE espec_cursor
-- Fetches the next section and returns to the top of the loop
FETCH NEXT FROM section_cursor
INTO @section, @sectionname, @order
PRINT ' '
PRINT ' '
END
-- Clear out the section_cursor as the procedure is over
CLOSE section_cursor
DEALLOCATE section_cursor
```

Comment: is this query from MS SQL Server?

Comment: this is code from Microsoft SQL Server since there is no @@FETCH_STATUS variable or PRINT statement in MySQL

Comment: it runs for following modification.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is something about mysql delimiter. Try to run it like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
-- Declare a cursor to hold the section information for a specified product 
DECLARE section_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT cds_especee.sectid, cds_evocee.text, min 
(displayorder) displayorder 
FROM cds_especee 
JOIN cds_evocee ON (cds_especee.sectid = cds_evocee.id) 
-- Replace the prodid below with a valid prodid from your data set 
WHERE cds_especee.prodid = 'S1522339' 
GROUP BY cds_especee.sectid, cds_evocee.text 
ORDER BY displayorder ASC 
OPEN section_cursor 
-- Fetching the first section into variable 
FETCH NEXT FROM section_cursor 
INTO @section, @sectionname, @order 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN 
-- Print current section to the screen 
PRINT '******'+@sectionname+'******' 
-- Declare a cursor to hold the header and body information for the 
specified product 
-- Note that the WHERE statement limits the results to the headers and body falling under the current section 
DECLARE espec_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT evoc1.text, evoc2.text, displayorder 
FROM cds_especee 
JOIN cds_evocee evoc1 ON (cds_especee.hdrid = evoc1.id) 
JOIN cds_evocee evoc2 ON (cds_especee.bodyid = evoc2.id) 
-- Replace the prodid below with a valid prodid from your data set 
WHERE cds_especee.prodid = 'S1522339' AND 
cds_especee.sectid = @section 
ORDER BY displayorder ASC 
OPEN espec_cursor 
-- Fetching the first header and body into variable 
FETCH NEXT FROM espec_cursor 
INTO @hdr, @body, @order1 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
-- Below is a loop that prints all the headers and bodies for the 
current section 
BEGIN 
PRINT @hdr +': '+@body 
FETCH NEXT FROM espec_cursor 
INTO @hdr, @body, @order1 
END 
-- Clear out the espec_cursor as it will be repopulated with data for 
the next section as the procedure loops 
CLOSE espec_cursor 
DEALLOCATE espec_cursor 
-- Fetches the next section and returns to the top of the loop 
FETCH NEXT FROM section_cursor 
INTO @section, @sectionname, @order 
PRINT ' ' 
PRINT ' ' 
END 
-- Clear out the section_cursor as the procedure is over 
CLOSE section_cursor 
DEALLOCATE section_cursor$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use many of those statements including DECLARE, OPEN, FETCH, CLOSE in a simple MySQL script. You should create a source object for this purpose. For example you could do it using stored procedure. There is a good example in the documentation - [Cursors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html).

Also PRINT is not MySQL statement.